# How can I return json output when application was requested via not allowed method(like PUT, DELETE...)?

Tags: python, api, flask

I'm implementing API using Flask.
The problem is that API returns error html page when api was requested via not-allowed methods. I want to return json value for this.
How can I do this in Flask?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Allow the method, then return the appropriate response code and JSON.

Comment: I don't want to allow not-allowed-method. But this is helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Simply use the [`errorhandler`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Flask.errorhandler) decorator or the [`register_error_handler`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Flask.register_error_handler) method to return the appropriate JSON:

```
@app.errorhandler(404)
def error_404():
    return jsonify(error="This resource does not exist"), 404
```